# Display Div based on Day and Time (Week and Weekend)

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where I would like to show or hide a div (class=hours) based on the time of day. I have been able to get this to work with the help of your collective genius from previous questions. However! I need to have different times for the weekend and the week days (weekends from 800 to 1400, and weekdays open from 600 to 1600).

I tried manipulating a javascript function that I was able to get working (after trying numerous other solutions) and it didn't seem to work. Please help!

The first example of code is how I was able to get the weekdays working. Below it is the code with the else if statement added for weekends.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var status = 'open';

    //Weekday hours 6AM to 4PM

    if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 6 && hour <= 16){
        if (hour=='6' && mins < '30'){
            status = 'closed';
        }else if (hour=='16' && mins > '30'){
            status = 'closed';
        }else{
            status = 'open';
        }
    }else{
        status = 'closed';
    }

    if (status=='open') {
        $('.hours').show();

    }else{
        $('.hours').hide();

    };

});
```

Here is the code that I manipulated hoping to make the weekend hour different by adding and else if statement in the existing code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var status = 'open';

    //Weekday hours 6AM to 4PM

    if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 6 && hour <= 16){
        if (hour=='6' && mins < '30'){
            status = 'closed';
        }else if (hour=='16' && mins > '30'){
            status = 'closed';
        }else{
            status = 'open';
        }
    //Weekend hours 8AM to 2PM    
    }else if (dayOfWeek !== 1 && dayOfWeek !== 2 && dayOfWeek !== 3 && dayOfWeek !== 4 && dayOfWeek !== 5 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 14){
        if (hour=='8' && mins < '30'){
            status = 'closed';
        }else if (hour=='14' && mins > '30'){
            status = 'closed';
        }else{
            status = 'open';
        }
    }else{
        status = 'closed';
    }

    if (status=='open') {
        $('.hours').show();

    }else{
        $('.hours').hide();

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account what you want to accomplish I would do the following:

- First create a function, so that you can test your code more easily.
- Since you are working with a finite number of weekdays (7) it might
  be advisable to use a `switch` instead of `if` to check this part of
  your date.
- If, as you say you need to test if your date is between 8:00 ~ 14:00
  on weekends, or 8:00 ~ 16:00 on weekdays the code will work
  correctly. This is because the range of hours is easier to test.

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    function setupHours(myDate){
        var dayOfWeek = myDate.getDay();
        var hour = myDate.getHours();
        var mins = myDate.getMinutes();
        var secs = myDate.getSeconds();
        var status = 'open';   
    
        switch(dayOfWeek){
          case 0: //sunday
           case 6: //Saturday
              console.log("Weekend");
              //from 8:00:00 to 13:59:59
              status =  (hour >= 8 && mins >= 0 && secs >= 0) && (hour <= 13 && mins <=59 && secs <= 59) ? 'open':'closed'       
              break;
           case 1: //Monday
           case 2://tusday
           case 3://wednesday
           case 4://thursday
           case 5: //friday
              console.log('weekday');
              //from 8:00:00 to 15:59:59
              status = (hour >= 8 && mins >= 0 & secs >= 0) && (hour <= 15 && mins <= 59 && secs <= 59) ? 'open':'closed'  
              break;
        }
        
        //TODO: delete, test case console log
        console.log("Status for: " +myDate+ " is " + status.toUpperCase());
    
        $('.hours').text(status);
    
    }
    
    //TODO: delete, for test cases only
    
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 7, 59, 00, 00)); // monday 7:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 8, 00, 00, 00)); // monday 8:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 15, 59, 59, 00)); // monday 15:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 16, 00, 00, 00)); // monday 16:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 16, 30, 00, 00)); // monday 16:30
    
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 7, 59, 00, 00)); // saturday 7:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 8, 00, 00, 00)); // saturday 8:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 13, 59, 59, 00)); // saturday 15:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 14, 00, 00, 00)); // saturday 16:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 14, 30, 00, 00)); // saturday 16:30
    
    //TODO: Non test code, keep as is
    setupHours(new Date());
  
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date-filtering" class="hours"></div>
```

EDIT:

---

For a more generic, and probably better solution you might try the following. Instead of comparing the actual numbers in hour and minute. It creates a two 
new dates that will serve as comparators for your actualDate. These two dates 
will represent your lowerDate and upperDate.

the function `testRange()` returns true or false depending on the test of the range.

Also as stated before I would also advice to use functions to isolate bits of functionality, as done in `testRange()` and `setupDate()`

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    function setupHours(myDate){
        var dayOfWeek = myDate.getDay();
        var status = 'open';         
            
        switch(dayOfWeek){
          case 0: //sunday
           case 6: //Saturday
              console.log("Weekend");
              //from 8:00:00 to 13:59:59
              status =  testRange(8,30, 14, 30, myDate) ? 'open':'closed' //Test your range      
              break;
           case 1: //Monday
           case 2://tusday
           case 3://wednesday
           case 4://thursday
           case 5: //friday
              console.log('weekday');
              //from 8:00:00 to 15:59:59
              status = testRange(8,30, 16, 30, myDate) ? 'open':'closed'   //Test your range
              break;
        }
        
        //TODO: delete, test case console log
        console.log("Status for: " +myDate+ " is " + status.toUpperCase());
    
        $('.hours').text(status);
    
    }
    
    function testRange(lHour,lMin, hHour ,hMin, actualDate){
   var lowDate = new Date(actualDate); //Create a new date based on the one you need to test
      lowDate.setHours(lHour); //set hour to your loweHour
      lowDate.setMinutes(lMin); //Set min to your lowerMin
      lowDate.setSeconds(0); //Set seconds to 0
      lowDate.setMilliseconds(0); //Set mill to 0
      
      var highDate = new Date(actualDate); //Create a new date based on the one you need to test
      highDate.setHours(hHour); //set hour to your higher our
      highDate.setMinutes(hMin); //set hour to you higher mir
      highDate.setSeconds(0);//Set seconds to 0
      highDate.setMilliseconds(0);//Set mill to 0
      
      return actualDate >= lowDate && actualDate <= highDate //Test if the actual date is in range. 
      
    }
    
    //TODO: delete, for test cases only
    
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 7, 59, 00, 00)); // monday 7:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 8, 00, 00, 00)); // monday 8:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 15, 59, 59, 00)); // monday 15:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 16, 00, 00, 00)); // monday 16:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 8, 16, 30, 00, 00)); // monday 16:30
    
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 7, 59, 00, 00)); // saturday 7:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 8, 00, 00, 00)); // saturday 8:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 13, 59, 59, 00)); // saturday 15:59
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 14, 00, 00, 00)); // saturday 16:00
    setupHours(new Date(2017, 4, 13, 14, 30, 00, 00)); // saturday 16:30
    
    //TODO: Non test code, keep as is
    setupHours(new Date());
  
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date-filtering" class="hours"></div>
```

Comment: This worked great! I have one remaining issue. I am trying to add an image into the string next to 'Open'. I need to only display during the open hours.

Comment: then instead of `$('.hours').text(status);` try using `$('.hours').toggle(status);` please refer to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ for more information on how to use jQuery toggle function. Then just add your image to the `<div class="hours"></div>`